# Regex : Get specific match for a multiline log

Tags: regex

I have a log which contain a structure like this :

OPEN
[multiline content]
START

OPEN
[multiline content]
START

OPEN
[multiline content]
START

I need to find the number of this occurence in my log, but sometime for weird reason, the log is like this :

OPEN
[multiline content]
OPEN
[multiline content]
START

(OPEN must have a START after, but in this case not).

I have basic regex like this : https://regex101.com/r/URPsTG/1

I want to match the part "OPEN ... START", so when the structure is

OPEN
[multiline content]
**OPEN
[multiline content]
START**

The bold part have to match, and the rest have to be ignored.

How to proceed that ?

Thanks !

Comment: `OPEN [multiline content] OPEN [multiline content] START` <-- does this count once, or twice?

Comment: Only count once in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `OPEN`, followed by all lines that do not start with `OPEN` or `START` to prevent overmatching.

```
^OPEN((?:\r?\n(?!(?:OPEN|START)$).*)*)\r?\nSTART
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `OPEN` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?!(?:OPEN|START)$)` Match a newline and assert that is does not start with either `OPEN` or `START`
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines
- `)` Close group 1
- `\r?\nSTART` Match a newline followed by START

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WedHF/1)

---

There is no language tagged, but if supported you could prevent some backtracking using an atomic group `(?>` (or make the quantifier for the outer non capture group possessive `*+`)

```
^OPEN((?>\r?\n(?!(?:OPEN|START)$).*)*)\r?\nSTART
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vOJx3h/1)

Answer (score 0):

This `(?:(?!^OPEN)OPEN.*?)?` prefix to your existing regex should do it:

```
/(?:(?!^OPEN)OPEN.*?)?OPEN(.*?)START/gms
```

Explanation:

- `(?:(?!^OPEN)OPEN.*?)?` - non-capturing group, optional, for `OPEN` not at the beginning of the text, followed by a non-greedy scan

Comment: Thank your for your super fast reply, i try it in regex101, it almost work but my first occurence of OPEN[...]START is not matched : https://regex101.com/r/JS8GqJ/2

Comment: Good catch. I fixed it with a negative lookahead, please try.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tempered dot here:

```regex
\bOPEN\b(?:(?!\bOPEN\b).)*?\bSTART\b
```

### Demo

This regex works by:

```
\bOPEN\b             match an initial "OPEN"
(?:(?!\bOPEN\b).)*?  match all content without passing another "OPEN"
                     until reaching the nearest/first
\bSTART\b            "START"
```

The second step of the above regex uses a "tempered dot" trick.  The negative lookahead makes sure that `.*` does not pass over another `OPEN`, which would mean that it is not the nearest one to the closing `START`.